# How to ensure a shared preference data is retained even after the app is uninstalled in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am trying to build a flutter app that will retain the shared preference data of a user even after the app is uninstalled. Upon re-installation, I want the shared preference data to remain the same. I have tried using `android:allowBackup="true" in the manifest.xml file but it is not working. Kindly assist. Thanks.`

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Shared preference data is stored as an xml file in your apps data folder. when you uninstall the app the folder gets removed, my suggestion is that you store such data in a firestore db and retrieve it during first run.
and the android:allowBackup is true by default and doesn't store your data when you uninstall, it only allows you to take a backup through adb. you can read about it  at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#allowbackup

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.